# Spring Integration InboundChannelAdapter for Cassandra

Tags: spring-integration

I want to write an `IntegrationFlow` that reads data from a `keyspace` in `cassandra` and write to a queue.

From what I have researched so far, I was not able to find an `InboundChannelAdapter` for reading rows from `cassandra`. I found a project on GitHub called [spring-integration-cassandra](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-cassandra), but I don't find an `InboundChannelAdapter`.

Is writing my own `InboundChannelAdapter` the only option for my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. That's only the option so far.

That project definitely needs more love. So, when you done with your own `CassandraMessageSource` implementation feel free to come back to us with the contribution to that project.